# Optimize product images before uploading?

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, product-images, optimization

I'm using the Magento Store in version 1.7.0.2. I have a question about the product images. Is it necessary to optimize the product images before uploading or does optimize Magento the corresponding image sizes depending on the application screen size automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Image optimization you Magento Provide the good functionality for `resize()` image so you can use that as per your requirement on when you want to use the Product Images.

```
<?php
 $img=Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->keepFrame(true)->resize( $imgSizeWidth, $imgSizeHeight );
?>
```

Hear 
`small_image` has two more property like `image` & `thumbnail`

`keepFrame(true)` means it will remove the white background when Image is crop.

`resize(width,height)` means specify height & width.

For product Listing page refer the `catalog/product/list.phtml` file.

For Detail Page refer `catalog/product/view/media.phtml` file in your Theme folder.
Hope you got proper answer.

Comment: Hello Keyul,thanks for your quick answer! But I don't know how to handle this php-code. In what file I have to write this code? Do you have an example?

Comment: I have update my answer please check

Comment: Oh thanks a lot!;) And one more thing: it is  harmful at all to the loading time of the Magento Stores, when I add an image file with a big size of 4MB?

Comment: when you use resize() function then Image automatic Comperes so don't worry

Comment: Ah that's fine - thanks a lot for your useful answers!

Comment: Hi Keyul, just one question: could it be this folder?
\template\magentothem\prozoom\media.phtml
The folder you wrote yesterday doesn't exist in my system...

Comment: yes if you are using custom extension form media then use this file